# changing spring mapping behaviour

Tags: database, spring, controller, mapping

I have an problem with my Save method in the controller

I have an form with an travel, with an optional travel back
What I try to do is, if travel2 all fields filled then save travel1+travel2
else only travel1

but logs says I can't, because it fails somewhere before in the annotations

edit: it crashs if date is not filled

```
#2result:org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'FormModel' on field 'travel2.traveldate': rejected value []; codes [typeMismatch.FormModel.travel2.traveldate,typeMismatch.travel2.traveldate,typeMismatch.traveldate,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [FormModel.travel2.traveldate,travel2.traveldate]; arguments []; default message [travel2.traveldate]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'travel2.traveldate'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.Date] for value ''; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]
```

so how can I change the behaviour without setting NULLABLE allowed in the DB?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveOrUpdateUser(@ModelAttribute("FormModel") @Validated FormModel formmodel, 
        BindingResult result, Model model, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {....
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
System.out.println("#2result:"+result);
//IF ...(formmodel.getTravel2().allFilled())
        //travelService.save(formmodel.getTravel(),formmodel.getTravel2());
```

the formmodel wrapperclass:

```
public class FormModel {
    private User user;
    private Costcenter costcenter;
    private Travel travel;
    private Travel travel2;...
```

the form:

```
<form:hidden path="travel2.t_id" />   
            <spring:bind path="travel2.traveldate">
                <div class="form-group has-feedback${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Travel Date</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <form:input path="travel2.traveldate" class="form-control"
                            id="datepicker2" type="text" placeholder="Traveldate" />
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar form-control-feedback"></span>
                        <form:errors path="travel2.traveldate" class="control-label" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </spring:bind>
```

edit:
maybe I could check the "result"
and do something like

```
if(no errors)-> keep going
elseif(error with date) //<<<<catch stuff here, if date not filled... result.getFieldError().getRejectedValue()==""
else show errorpage
```

edit2: the Travel class

```
public class Travel {
Integer t_id;

Date traveldate;    
Time starttime;
String start;
String destination;

public Integer gett_id() {
    return t_id;
}

public void sett_id(Integer t_id) {
    this.t_id = t_id;
}...
public boolean allFilled(){
    if (traveldate!=null && starttime!= null 
        && start !=null && start !=""
        && destination != null && destination != ""){
    return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}....
```

Comment: post your `Travel` class

Answer (score 0):

In the error logs, it is clearly mentioned that there is a type mismatch with the property travelDate in your Travel class. You might be using Date type in your domain class, but when you fill the values for the same field in the UI page, it will post the value in the String format. Try changing the code of getter and setter methods of travelDate using the below reference.

```
private Date createdOn;

public String getCreatedOn() {
    String dateInString=null;
    if(createdOn!=null){
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        dateInString = df.format(createdOn);
    }
    return dateInString;
}
public void setCreatedOn(String createdOn) {
    try {

        SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        this.createdOn = sdf.parse(createdOn);
    } catch(ParseException e) {
        this.createdOn=null;  
    }        
}
```

Post the code of UI page if this does not seems working.

Comment: thx, but the Date type problem was solved on friday. now is the problem if I have no value for date of travel2->got the error.
 if I pick an date it works. but I'll check it